Publishing a C4R models on BIM 360 Teams before EOL
We are running into an issue with BIM Teams Data migration. We have Revit C4R models which need to be published before migration. Revit version 2017, 2018 and above.
We need support from APs on the API command to execute the cmd given below. 
Currently we are using commands:autodesk.a360:C4RModelPublish
We need an equivalent command to publish C4R models. 
Please help us out onto what is the appropriate command and API instance. 
we have tried to call this API endpoint.
URL : https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/a.VzaW5MyMDE3MTEwMTEHAHASHWahah/commands
3 legged token for Auth.
and body of the request is given below.
{
"jsonapi": {
"version": "1.0"
},
"data": {
"type": "commands",
"attributes": {
"extension": {
"type": "commands:autodesk.bim360:C4RModelPublish",
"version": "1.0.0"
}
},
"relationships": {
"resources": {
"data": [
{
"type": "items",
"id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:5oR_FjdheSiIlou4njheLAJS"
}
]
}
}
}
}

Hi, this is currently not supported, but let's have a separate talk based on this request, I saw you requested a meeting on calendly, will check with my colleage and talk to you there.

Thank you for your response Zhong. looking forward to resolve this in our meeting. Thanks

Unfortunately, I believe this commands:autodesk.a360:C4RModelPublish is only supported for BIM 360 Docs and ACC Docs, it does not support the RCW on BIM 360 Team.
